# how to solve datatable selected row when filter search in jquery and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to my table first row selected when search table row column but i have also put selected first row selected code but that's not working how can i solve?

```js
var table = this.oTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  "lengthMenu": [
    [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
    [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
  ],
  scrollX: true,
  scrollY: $(window).height() - 232,
  "stateSave": true,
  "info": true,
  // "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
  "ordering": true,
  "order": [
    [1, "desc"]
  ],
  language: {
    oPaginate: {
      sNext: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
      sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left  "></i>',
      sFirst: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>',
      sLast: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>'
    },
    "sProcessing": '<div class="fulloverlay"> <img id="loading-image" src="' + base_url + '/assets/v1/images/loader.gif"> </div>',
  },
  columnDefs: [{
      targets: [0],
      "orderable": false,

    },
    {
      "orderable": false,
      targets: [0, 2]
    }
  ],
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": base_url + 'index.php/Customer_Category/tableList1',
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "iDisplayStart ": 20,
  "pageLength": 40,
  searching: false,
  orderCellsTop: true,
  fixedHeader: true,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "fnInitComplete": function() {},
  'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    var cnt = 0;
    $('#mytable thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function(i) {
      if ($("#searchFilter_" + cnt).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
        if ($("#searchFilter_" + cnt).prop("checked") == true) {
          var val = 1;
        } else if ($("#searchFilter_" + cnt).prop("checked") == false) {
          var val = 0;
        }
        aoData.push({
          "name": "searchFilter_" + cnt,
          "value": val
        });
      } else {
        aoData.push({
          "name": "searchFilter_" + cnt,
          "value": $("#searchFilter_" + cnt).val()
        });
      }
      cnt++;
    });

    $.ajax({
      'dataType': 'json',
      'type': 'POST',
      'url': sSource,
      'data': aoData,
      'success': fnCallback
    });
  },
  rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
      $(row).removeClass('myodd myeven');
      $(row).addClass('myodd');
    } else {
      $(row).removeClass('myodd myeven');
      $(row).addClass('myeven');
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initComplete` to select first record.

```
$('#mytable').DataTable( {
    "initComplete": function () {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
        table.row(':eq(0)', { page: 'current' }).select();

    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/9859/)